# Why is String.indexOf functioning like this?

Tags: javascript, diacritics

I'm trying to match some text based on a query that the user inputs. After encountering some issues, I found out this rather odd behaviour of `String.indexOf` that I simply cannot understand:

If I try to match a query without diacritics against a string with diacritics, it works: (not sure why)

```
"brezzel cu brânză".indexOf("bra")
```

> 11

But matching the same string with another letter after it, doesn't work:

```
"brezzel cu brânză".indexOf("bran")
```

> -1

(tested both in Chrome & Firefox, same behaviour)

Is this a documented behaviour that I'm unaware of or what exactly is happening here?

Comment: `a` is not equal to `â`.. `brân` is in the string but `bran` is not in the string

Comment: in case these chars look the same to you(your display is STRANGE), run some code in a js console.. `console.log("a"=="â")`

Comment: `Array.from("brânză")` reveals what exactly is in the string.

Comment: That "a" character in your source string is comprised of the normal latin "a" plus the "combining circumflex accent" character, Unicode code point 770 (decimal).

Comment: Related: [Javascript - normalize accented greek characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23346506/4642212) and [Seemingly identical strings fail comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16799810/4642212).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, js characters are encoded in 2 bytes. But many other unicode chars encoded 4 bytes. Now the char â is 4 bytes. The first 2 bytes is a, thats why the first case works. Use the escape function to see:

```
escape("brezzel cu brânză")
"brezzel%20cu%20bra%u0302nza%u0306"
```

see that `%20` is space, followed by bra and then you have `%u0302` which together with previous `a`, encodes `â`.

Probably you can tell the rest. Test it if you want to:

```
'a' + String.fromCharCode('0x0302') //â
```