# jQuery not work condition with Germany charset

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem with condition of Germany charset:

```
if (jQuery(this).find("dt").text()=="Kälteleistung")
```

Its always return false but in `jQuery(this).find("dt").text()` alert print `Kälteleistung`

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805711/javascript-string-comparison-fails-when-comparing-unicode-characters

Comment: jQuery("<div/>").html("K&auml;lteleistung").text() This help me. Strange community. Guys closed my question instead solution his. Lol

Comment: if(jQuery(this).find("dt").text()==jQuery("<div/>").html("K&auml;lteleistung").text())

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_dt.asp

Comment: Ah, right. That's the one I always forget. Was my answer helpful btw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(jQuery(this).find("dt").text()==jQuery("<div/>").html("K&auml;lteleistung").t‌​ext())
```

This simple solution help me. There are we are find special char of `ä` char. We are formed string for condition `"K&auml;lteleistung"` and our task is return string which be same as we take in our html. We are need place it to html `jQuery("<div/>").html("K&auml;lteleistung")` and take it `.t‌​ext()`. Very simple and clear solution which does not require a third-party libraries.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got your question working, without the need of extra stuff. I think your problem is in the selector not working good (there is no need to use `find`).

I have [this sample](http://jsfiddle.net/V9L8V/), returning 'ok':

```
<div>Kälteleistung</div>

<script>
    if ($("div").text()=="Kälteleistung")
    {
        alert('ok');
    }
    else
    {
        alert('not ok');
    }
</script>
```