# How can I compare 2 strings with accents

Tags: javascript, string, compare

I have 2 strings:

```
var a = 'António'
var b = 'António'
```

But when I compare them:

```
if(a == b)
```

They are not equal. How can a make that true?

Comment: If i copy/paste i get true for `var a = 'António', b = 'António'; a == b`  if you do not then one of the strings has a charcter(s) difference, this may include invisible unicode characters.  Please provide a test case that returns `false`.

Comment: While I am checking it in console it shows true

var a = 'António' , b = 'António'
console.log(a==b?true : false)

Comment: @NairAthul `(a==b)?true : false`...C'mon - You can't do that

Comment: try it in console. It will give you result :)

Comment: (a==b) *already* returns true|false

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript string comparison fails when comparing unicode characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805711/javascript-string-comparison-fails-when-comparing-unicode-characters)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`String.prototype.localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) method.

```
stringA.localeCompare(stringB);

/* Expected Returns:

 0:  exact match

-1:  stringA < stringB

 1:  stringA > stringB

 */
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem happens because your `'ó'` character might be expressed differently.

You can obtain the same grapheme by writing:

1. Using the Unicode character

   `var a = 'António'`
2. Using the Unicode code point

   `var b = 'Ant\u00F3nio'`
3. Using a combining mark ('o' + '´')

   `var c = 'Anto\u0301nio'`

The last one combines 'o' (latin small letter o) with '´' (accute accent).

Now if you do `a === b` you will get `true`. Because in this case I used the Unicode character and compared it with its code point which is the same thing.

Now if you do `a === c` you will get `false`. Because the first one is one Unicode character and the second one is combining an Unicode character with a combining mark obtaining the same grapheme.

Now if I'm pasting `a` and `c` output in the console, then copy pasting them into other variables and comparing them, I will get the same thing.

Doing: `var x = 'António'` (from `a`) and `var y = 'António'` (from `c`) then `x === y` will get `false`. If you try this in your browser console and you get `false` then is right, else SO might have processed the string and no wonder others got `true`.

In order to compare `a` (`'António'`) with `c` (`'Anto\u0301nio'`), you need to normalize the form in order to get the same thing.

Therefore you can do:

**NFC (Canonically-composed form)** (the default)

`a === c.normalize('NFC')` or just `a === c.normalize()`

Therefore this makes `c` to be represented the same as `a`.

**NFD (Canonically-decomposed form)**

`a.normalize('NFD') === c`

Therefore this makes `a` to be represented the same as `c`.

Or you can just rely on one form for both sides and don't mind the format used to represent any of the strings:

`a.normalize() === c.normalize()`

**NOTE:** JavaScript engines use UTF-16. This means that if your character is in the Basic Multilingual Plane having the code point between `U+0000` and `U+FFFF` you will be good. But if you use some character above that range (Astral Planes) then that character will be represented using surrogate pairs thus having two code units 16-bit each. In that case some operations might not yield the expected behavior if the string is not normalized.

**NOTE:** for a good read you can check [this](https://rainsoft.io/what-every-javascript-developer-should-know-about-unicode/).

Answer (score -1):

`a == b` returns true for me. As a side note you should probably use `===`

Answer (score -1):

```js
var a = "António";
var b = "António";

$(document).ready(function(){
 if(a == b){
   alert(true);
  }else{
   alert(false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```